# PHP Netbeans coding style configuration, where is it?

Tags: php, coding-style, netbeans

I want to standardize coding style accross all the developers computers in my office, I want to export my netbeans configuration and ask the other programmers to import it on their IDEs, do you know where that config file is?

I'm using netbeans 8.02 but if you have found it on another version I can use that information to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can export your preferences via Tools|Options and use the "Export..." button on the bottom left corner. Check the "Formatting" checkboxe(s) to export formatting preferences only.
It will export your settings to a ZIP file.

To import these settings on other computers, simply go to Tools|Options and use the "Import..." button ;)

Comment: This is very cool, thanks! However, on the php exporting options I can only select the indentation option.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that some settings are stored in hyperspace. So while that makes your efforts (to pass settings files around) futile, on the bright side it does mean interstellar travel is one step closer!

My experimental proof is to use this from inside the `~/.netbeans/` folder:

```
find . -mtime 1
```

I then altered some settings, closed netbeans, ran the above command again, and looked for which files changed. Nothing plausible seemed to, and the implausible ones did not contain anything that looked like my changes. I also ran the same test on the Project's `nbproject` folder (nothing had changed), and also had a poke around inside `/etc/` (there seem to be no NetBeans files there).  Yet, when I restart NetBeans, and go and look at the Options again (Editor | Formatting | PHP, then "Blank Lines" was where I did my test changes), my changes are still there.

So it is either Hyperspace, or Magic. And being a scientist I am not allowed to believe in magic. QED.